# HTML5 won't play multiple instances of same file until first is played

Tags: javascript, html, apache, html5-audio

First, some background information. I am running a prototype site with the standard XAMPP configuration.

The problem I am having is this. When I load multiple audio tags to a single page, I don't come across an issue until I load the same song more than once.

When this happens, any reference below the first can't be loaded/played until the first one is at least played, then paused.

Also, if you try to play them both, only the first one to be triggered will play (not as big of an issue). Here is a screenshot of the issue:

update: It seems that when playing one of the duplicate songs, it will randomly stop and the other duplicate will start playing.

update 2: I have checked multiple sites and haven't found a solution to this problem. May be an issue with how the browsers play the files.

[image: a]